Picamera2 frame rate cap
I just found out that in picamera2 python scripts, the frame rate is capped at 30, how can i use it to capture sth at 50 fps?
I have included the snapshot of the code.
I tried to use 'control' parameter, but it is still capped.Snapshot of the github python script

what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

how to ask a good question:
how to ask
